# How to perform a bulk insert via sails-mongo and sails.js?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

Is there a way to perform a bulk insert via sails-mongo. So if I pass an array of documents to the model's create method, it will insert each document within that array atomically into the database?

Comment: I have tried passing the array directly into Model.create() (with Model being the name of my given model) and I have also tried Model.createEach()... it just indexes it as an actual array, rather than as each document in the array as you would expect from a batch insert with mongodb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works exactly like you asked:

```
Model.create([{foo: "first},{foo:"2nd"}]).exec(...
```

See http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Model-Methods/create.html

Comment: Does this only work in the beta version, or will it work in stable version (0.9.x)?

Comment: This looks great. Will it also work for Model.findOrCreate() ? If so what would be the syntax?  Thanks

Comment: @KevinBaker: Yes - see: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/findOrCreate.html. You can use several records or criteria